# ошибка при первоначальной миграции базы данных

Tags: laravel

Делаю миграцию базы данных согласно пошаговому руководству по ссылке: https://bootcamp.laravel.com/blade/installation вводя команду php artisan migrate. В результате получаю в выводе текст ошибки:

```
PS D:\Web App2022\webApp> php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  Database (D:\Web App2022\webApp\database\database.sqlite) does not exist. (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

  at D:\Web App2022\webApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

В связи с чем у меня вопрос: нужно ли создавать базу данных в этом случае, если да то в какой папке и вообще как решить вопрос с этой ошибкой?

Comment: в .env файле пропишите настройки бд, без них никуда

Comment: @InDevX, а если я использую sqlite? В переменную среды надо прописать DB_CONNECTION=sqlite, согласно руководству, надо оставить только эту строчку и я это сделал, но тем не менее у меня такая ошибка. Тогда что я должен сделать?

Comment: в DB_DATABASE надо прописать надо весь путь к database.sqlite файлу

Comment: @InDevX, этот файл должен уже быть после создания проекта(после того как была выполнена команда сomposer create-app ... ) или его нужно создавать?

Comment: Это не зависит от проэкта, вы выбираете какую бд юзать и ставите её, тот же sqlite как пример в доках, можете mysql, postresql и пр. юзать

Comment: @InDevX, помогло создание файла database.sqlite в папке проекта без указания к нему пути.